# Homomorphisms of the group of affine trasformations

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following theorem.

> Let $\mathrm{Aff}(n)$ define the set of transformations $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ sending $x \mapsto Ax + b$ such that $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that (a) $\psi: \mathrm{Aff}(n) \to \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$ sending $T \mapsto A$ is a homomorphism of groups, but that (b) $\phi: \mathrm{Aff}(n) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ sending $T \mapsto b$ is not.

My key problem in (a) is formalism. I want to act on an arbitrary element of $x$, but I can't do that because inputs to $\psi$ are elements of $\mathrm{Aff}(n)$, not of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I need to do the casework "outside" of the main equation chain, since it doesnt make sense for me to write $\psi((T_1 \circ T_2)(x))$ or $\varphi(T_1)(x)$. With that said, here is my attempt that I believe to be insufficiently formal.

> Let $T_i \in \mathrm{Aff}(n)$ sending $x \longmapsto A_i x + b_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we h ave
> \begin{align*}
> (T_1 \circ T_2)(x) & = T_1(T_2 (x)) \\
> & = T_1 (A_2 x + b_2) \\
> & = A_1 (A_2 x + b_2) + b_1 \\
> & = (A_1 A_2)x + (A_1 b_2 + b_1)
> \end{align*}
> So
> \begin{align*}
> \psi(T_1 T_2) = A_1 A_2 = \psi(T_1) \psi(T_2).
> \end{align*}

The problem, again, is that I can't define the output of $\psi$ without referring to $x$.

> I'm less sure on part (b), so this is more scratchwork than much else. Take $T_1, T_2$ defined as above. Then, using the above work, we get:
> \begin{align*}
> \phi(T_1 T_2) & = A_1 b_2 + b_1 \\
> \phi(T_1) + \phi(T_2) & = b_1 + b_2
> \end{align*}
> But $A_1 b_2 + b_1 \neq b_1 + b_2$ in general. Indeed, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> A_1 b_2 + b_1 = b_1 + b_2 & \iff A_1 b_2 = b_2 \iff A_1 = I.
> \end{align*}
> So specifying $T_1$ with any $A_1 \neq I$ gives a counterexample.

This is not an explicit counterexample and I don't quite know how to construct one for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For a group homomorphism $\psi\colon G\rightarrow H$ you also need to show that $G$ and $H$ are groups. Since you only know that ${\rm Aff}(n)$ is the **set** of affine transformations, you should show that it forms a group. The title was misleading here, so I changed it. You can change it back of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you struggle to show that $\psi$ satifsies the homomorphism property

$$\phi (T \circ S) =\phi(T) \phi(S)$$

Suppose $T(x) = Ax + a$ and $S(x) = Bx + b$. We have

$$(T \circ S)(x) = T(Bx + b) = A(Bx+b)+a = (AB)x + (Ab + a)$$

Hence, $\psi(T \circ S) = A B = \psi(T) \psi(S)$.

Now, you see from the computation above why $\phi$ is not a homomorphism. Since

$$\phi(T \circ S) = Ab + a,$$

which in general does not equal $\phi(T) + \phi(S) = a + b$.

We give the following counter example: Let $T$ and $S$ be given by

\begin{align}
T(x) &= \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} x + \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \end{bmatrix} \\
S(x) &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} x + \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

A simple computation shows that

$$(T \circ S)(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \end{bmatrix}$$.

Hence, $\phi(T \circ S) = (1,1)^\top$, whereas $\phi(T) + \phi(S) = (1,0)^\top + (1,2)^\top = (2,2)^\top$.

Comment: There was a typo in part (b). I meant to say that $\phi$ maps into $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: No problem. I have edited my answer to explain why $\phi$ is not a homomorphism into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: It makes sense to me that $Ab + a \neq a + b$ in general, but I'm trying to find a canonical counterexample. Is it correct to say that $Ab + a = a + b$ if and only if $A = I$?

Comment: Not necessarily, $A$ may be a matrix with $b$ as an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. However, it is not difficult to find a counterexample in the case $n=2$. Try matrices with a lot of zeros and let the $a$ and $b$ not resemble each other too much.

Comment: Hmm, but this statement has to work for any $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then then we would have $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$ for all $b$, so it must be a multiple of the identity matrix. So anything not of that form (e.g., an $n \times n$ rotation matrix, which is surely invertible) would work as a counterexample. Is that right?

Comment: I have now given a concrete counter example in the answer. If every vector is an eigenvector, the matrix is of course the identity, but that is not the point. The point is that there will be affine transformations for which $\phi(T \circ S) = \phi(T) + \phi(S)$, but it will not be true in general.